# Если после запятой больше 2 - х знаков отбросит остаток

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Нужно на javascript сделать так:

```
if(в этом числе 5,4444 знаков после запятой больше чем два) {
    то преобразуем в 5,44
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var numb = 123.23454;
numb = numb.toFixed(2);
console.log(numb)
```